# Read unix timestamps as POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I need to read timestamps from unix. Example:
Wed Jun  1 15:22:41 EDT 2022

I tried to read in the timezone in as.POSIXct using the tz argument.

```
time.char <- "Wed Jun  1 15:22:41 EDT 2022"
time.char <- sub("^... ","",time.char)
tz <- sub(".+ ([^ ]+) [0-9]{4}$","\\1",time.char)
timedate <- sub("(.+) [^ ]+ ([0-9]{4})$","\\1 \\2",time.char)
time.posixct <- as.POSIXct(timedate,format="%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",tz=tz)
## I thought I was done
print(time.posixct)
[1] "2022-06-01 15:22:41 EDT"
## But the timezone isn't real. UTC is used.
time.now <- Sys.time()
print(time.now)
[1] "2022-06-01 15:27:25 EDT"
time.now-time.posixct
Time difference of 4.079089 hours
```

The problem seems to be I need to do tz="America/New_York". How can I make use of the three-letter time zones codes provided by unix?

Comment: does this `as.POSIXct(time.char, format="%a %b %d %T EDT %Y")` help?

Comment: Thanks onyambu. No, that doesn't use the timezone information. The time zone can vary between time stamps. In this example it's EDT, but it could be CET or something else. The problem is the time zones my R session is using are to my understanding in the "America/New_York" format.

Comment: The timezones EDT/EAT/EST etc do not have uniqueness hense the normal is to use the 'timezone region'/location format by Olson. Check `OlsonNames` function in R. so far I dont know of a  way to translate EST to America/New York.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this is the output you're asking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

time.char <- tibble(time = "Wed Jun  1 15:22:41 EDT 2022")

time.char %>%
  mutate(time = str_replace_all(time, "  ", " ")) %>%
  separate(
    time,
    into = c("abb_weekday", "month", "day", "time", "tz", "year"),
    sep = " "
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    time_conc = paste0(year, "-", month, "-", day,
                       " ", time),
    time_adj = as.POSIXct(
      time_conc,
      tz = "America/New_York",
      tryFormats = c("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%OS")
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 8
#>   abb_weekday month day   time     tz    year  time_conc     time_adj           
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dttm>             
#> 1 Wed         Jun   1     15:22:41 EDT   2022  2022-Jun-1 1… 2022-06-01 15:22:41
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Desmond. The issue is to read the timestamp with the time zone, in this case "EDT". In your suggestion, you are hardcoding the translation to "America/New_York". It is essentially this translation that needs to be automated.